# Can you use the が particle in a sentence asking 何ですか?

Tags: grammar, particle-が

I've read that が is the particle used when asking a question, but then I see sentences like 一番好きな本はなんですか or 一番いい先生はだれですか.

Is there a reason why が is not used in this type of sentence, or is the rule re: が in a question sentence just a vague guideline?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have misunderstood the advice you were given. It is not true that が must be used in questions or that は cannot be. But because interrogative words like なに, だれ, etc. refer to undefined objects, it does not make sense to use the topic particle は with them. So if they are the subject of the sentence, then they *must* be marked with が rather than は. I believe this is all they were trying to get at.

For example:

> × だれ**は**電球を発明したの。
>   ○ だれ**が**電球を発明したの。

The question can, however, be rephrased as

> 電球を発明したの**は**だれ

without any problem.

Comment: I think it may help if you could you comment on 一番いい先生**が**だれですか? Is that grammatical (I don't think so), but if so, in what scenario could it be used? Thanks.